# How can I concatenate multiple optional strings in swift 3.0?

Tags: string, swift, swift3

I am trying to concatenate multiple strings in swift 3:

```
var a:String? = "a"
var b:String? = "b"
var c:String? = "c"
var d:String? = a! + b! + c!
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'String?'
var d:String? = a! + b! + c!
                ~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

This used to work in swift 2. I am not sure why it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bug report filed by OP:

- [SR-1122: Failure to typecheck chain of binary operators on force-unwrapped values](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1122)

Which has been resolved (fix commited to master Jan 3 2017), and should hence no longer be an issue in upcoming Swift 3.1.

---

This seems to be a bug (not present in Swift 2.2, only 3.0) associated with the case of:

- Using the forced unwrapping operator (`!`) for at least 3 terms in an expression (tested using at least 2 basic operators, e.g. `+` or `-`).
- For some reason, given the above, Swift messes up type inference of the expression (specifically, for the `x!` terms themselves, in the expression).

For all the examples below, let:

```
let a: String? = "a"
let b: String? = "b"
let c: String? = "c"
```

**Bug present:**

```
// example 1
a! + b! + c!
    /* error: ambiguous reference to member '+' */

// example 2
var d: String =  a! + b! + c!
    /* error: ambiguous reference to member '+' */

// example 3
var d: String? =  a! + b! + c!
    /* error: cannot convert value of type 'String' 
       to specified type 'String?' */

// example 4
var d: String?
d =  a! + b! + c!
    /* error: cannot assign value of type 'String' 
       to specified type 'String?' */

// example 5 (not just for type String and '+' operator)
let a: Int? = 1
let b: Int? = 2
let c: Int? = 3
var d: Int? = a! + b! + c!
    /* error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' 
       to specified type 'Int?' */
var e: Int? = a! - b! - c! // same error
```

**Bug not present:**

```
/* example 1 */
var d: String? = a! + b!

/* example 2 */
let aa = a!
let bb = b!
let cc = c!
var d: String? = aa + bb + cc
var e: String = aa + bb + cc

/* example 3 */
var d: String? = String(a!) + String(b!) + String(c!)
```

---

However as this is Swift 3.0-**dev**, I'm uncertain if this is really a "bug", as well as what's the policy w.r.t. reporting "bugs" in a not-yet-production version of code, but possibly you should file radar for this, just in case.

As for answering your question as how to circumvent this issue:

- use e.g. intermediate variables as in *Bug not present: Example 2* above,
- or explicitly tell Swift all terms in the 3-term expression are strings, as in *Bug not present: Example 3* above,
- or, better yet, use *safe unwrapping* of your optional, e.g. using *optional binding*:

  ```
  var d: String? = nil
  if let a = a, b = b, c = c {
      d = a + b + c
  } /* if any of a, b or c are 'nil', d will remain as 'nil';
       otherwise, the concenation of their unwrapped values   */
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I filed a bug [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1122)

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3

```
let q: String? = "Hello"
let w: String? = "World"
let r: String? = "!"
var array = [q, w, r]

print(array.flatMap { $0 }.reduce("", {$0 + $1}))
// HelloWorld!


let q: String? = "Hello"
let w: String? = nil
let r: String? = "!"
var array = [q, w, r]

print(array.flatMap { $0 }.reduce("", {$0 + $1}))
// Hello!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func getSingleValue(_ value: String?..., seperator: String = " ") -> String? {

    return value.reduce("") {
        ($0) + seperator + ($1 ?? "")
        }.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: seperator) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let val: String? = "nil"

val.flatMap({(str: String) -> String? in
    return str + "value"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a:String? = "a"
var b:String? = "b"
var c:String? = "c"
var d:String? = ""

let arr = [a,b,c]
arr.compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: " ")
```

compactMap be used to filter out nil values from flattened arrays

Comment: While your code might work, it would be nice if you would add a few explanations to your answer.