# Swift 3; Appending optional string with non-optional string

Tags: ios, swift, string, option-type, swift3

I just updated to Xcode 8.0 beta 2 and swift 3.0, and I'm getting an error in some of my existing swift 2.3-code, regarding optional strings:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and
>   'String!'

The variable "store" is an instance of a "Store"-object with properties `addressStreet` and `addressCity`, both defined as `var addressStreet: String!`

I'm getting the error on the `addressLabel.text = ...` line

```
if store != nil {
    addressLabel.text = store!.addressStreet + String(", ") + store!.addressCity
}
```

I don't get it! to me, it seems that none of the strings are optional, why am i getting this error, and how can i fix it?

Comment: Odd, this works in Swift 2.2 http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/577d1066fc6e90d25e4ad0d5

Comment: You really shouldn't abuse implicitly unwrapped optionals like this.

Comment: I believe this is a known bug, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315692/how-can-i-concatenate-multiple-optional-strings-in-swift-3-0/36318396#36318396) for details (bug report [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1122)).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, can you show your `Store` class code?

Comment: It seems to be a bug.. replacing String(", ") with ", " solved my problem.

Comment: Why would you use `String(", ")` anyway? You shoudl use `String(String(String(", ")))` instead ;)

Comment: Dunno.. Some old code, I must have had some issue with it previously...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's crash but code below more safe and doesn't have `'String'` + `'String!'` problem. Try it:

```
if let store = store, street = store.addressStreet, city = store.addressCity {
    addressLabel.text = "\(street), \(city)"
}
```

Comment: `addressLabel.text = street + ", " + city` is better, IMO.

Comment: @AMomchilov what's about `"\(street), \(city)"`? `street + ", " + city` looks too PHP for me :)

Comment: `street + ", " + city` is the most concise and clear. If there were more than 3-4 items, than I would say `joined` would be better

Comment: I agree with @Arsen that `"\(street), \(city)"` is more readable (and it has the added benefit that we don't have to wonder whether `street` and `city` are strings or not).