# Swift 3: Joining multiple Strings with "+" operator no longer possible

Tags: ios, xcode, string, swift3, ambiguous

In swift 2.3 I had this working simple piece of code:

```
let joinedString = partOne! + PartTwo! + PartThree! + PartFour!
```

Now with the conversion to swift 3 I've been bashing my head in over about 24 errors out of the blue with the most vague explanations.. This is one of them:

The same line of code gives error:

```
Ambiguous reference to member '+'
```

However if I split them up like so:

```
let OneAndTwo = partOne! + partTwo!
let ThreeAndFour = partThree! + PartFour!
let joinedString = OneAndTwo + ThreeAndFour
```

This works... Did they remove linking multiple strings like this or is it buggy? Seems like the compiler thinks the '+' is a variable or something else named the same?

EDIT:

Even though it's another error this seems to be related to: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315692/how-can-i-concatenate-multiple-optional-strings-in-swift-3-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Also crashes once you go upwards of 2 optional strings. I guess optional binding is the way to go then. Seems like this bug has been there for quite some time.

Comment: Look [at this demo](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57d8fcb1f623dd089776d581) (Swift Ver. 3.0 (Release), Platform: Linux (x86_64)) - if you just use strings, you can combine them with `+`.

Comment: Thanks.. My four parts were String as well but they are optionals. (The method that joins them only acts when they surely exist though) so perhaps that was part of the issue.. I'll continue using my two part approach but still very curious as to the why :)

Comment: To add: I just tried it with optionals and the sandbox crashes with the same error but some more info. Even the print line joining the three crashes once you add the third option: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57d8fea044c863091c3eaf7c

Comment: Another workaround: `let joinedString = "" + partOne! + partTwo! + partThree! + partFour!`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug and I'll investigate further. If we simulate the behaviour of `!` with another operator it works just fine:

```
postfix operator |! {}
postfix func |! <T>(rhs: T?) -> T {
    return rhs!
}

let s1: String? = "Hello"
let s2: String? = " "
let s3: String? = "World"
let joined = s1|! + s2|! + s3|! // "Hello World"
```

Comment: Thanks let us know if you find something else. I edited a link in above. Apparently the bug has been there for quite some time and sometimes indicates the String as a culprit and in my case the operator depending on the "joinedString" variable being optional or not.