# Swift 3 - Can't subtract variables: Ambiguous reference to member [subtraction]

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm just working through converting my app to Swift 3, and have come across an error I can't get my head around. The original line of code (swift2) looks like this:

```
return (self.a! - self.b! - self.c! - self.d!)!
```

The error given is `Ambiguous reference to member '-'`.

The obvious thing I thought was to try this:

```
return (4 - 5 - 6 - 7)
```

Which as you'd expect, works fine, so I'm guessing it's something to do with the variable types, which are all `Int?`.

Weirdly though, this works:

```
return (self.a! - self.b!) // only two variables
```

Could anybody explain why I can't now perform this subtraction, when I could before, and perhaps explain why swift thinks a `-` sign is Ambiguous?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems related to [the bug covered in this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315692/how-can-i-concatenate-multiple-optional-strings-in-swift-3-0/36318396#36318396): according to [the bug report (SR-1122)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1122) it is still unresolved.

Comment: I agree - thanks you. I've 'fixed' by creating a new constant for each of the variables i.e. `if let a = self.a, let b = self.b` etc.

Comment: That's the safer approach anyway. If you're force unwrapping something you should be completely ok with your app crashing at that point. otherwise, don't do it.,