# Swift gives "Ambiguous reference to member '+'" when trying to add more than two unwrapped optionals?

Tags: swift

I'm using Swift 3.0 and playgrounds in Xcode and I have a strange error I'm getting in Swift and I can't figure out the cause of it.

I have this code, which works just fine:

```
var reading1:Float? = 3.9
var reading2:Float? = 4.3
var reading3:Float? = 7.2

let averageReading = reading1! + reading2!
```

Now if I try and add a third value to the average reading, like so:

```
var reading1:Float? = 3.9
var reading2:Float? = 4.3
var reading3:Float? = 7.2

let averageReading = reading1! + reading2! + reading3! //This line errors
```

I get an error stating "Ambiguous references to member '+'" and it has me completely stumped. I don't understand why I can't simply add a third forcibly unwrapped optional.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Clarification on Swift version.

Comment: What happens if you try `averageReading = (reading1! + reading2!) + reading3!` ?

Comment: I get the same error. Parentheses don't seem to matter in this context.

Comment: I have no answer, but this is my WTF Oh well workaround: `let averageReading = (reading1! + reading2!) as Float + reading3!` Somehow the type-inferencing engine is afloat mid-expression (hah hah hah...)

Comment: Thanks! 

Also (figures) after I posted I saw this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315692/how-can-i-concatenate-multiple-optional-strings-in-swift-3-0/36318396#36318396

It looks like it's a known bug and filed already (at least for string concatenation).