# cannot subscript a value of type 'inout' [String :Double] (aka inout Dictionary<String, Double>)

Tags: dictionary, swift2, swift3, xcode8

How can if i try to add three menus in the dictionary i wont let me and throws an error when i try to force unwrap the 3rd item in the menu. However if i force unwrap two of them, i can get them sum of two

```
var menu = ["fish": 10.99, "chips": 5.99, "kebab": 6.99]
var totalCost = menu["fish"]! + menu["chips"]! + menu["kebab"]!
print("The total cost of the three items is \(totalCost)")
```

But when i tried it this way it worked

```
var menu = ["fish": 10.99, "chips": 5.99, "kebab": 6.99]
var totalCost = menu["fish"]! + menu["chips"]! 
var thisCost = totalCost + menu["kebab"]!
print("The total cost of the three items is \(thisCost)"
```

I am using swift 3. Could it be that can no longer be supported in swift 3?

Comment: In your first one the keys you use when creating the dictionary don't match the keys when you access it. i.e. "tuna" != "fish" and "steak" != "kebab".

Comment: @JamesSnook thats not the reason as to why, i just edited it back to its original form and that still doesnt want.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me, the first snippet should work, and the error message makes no sense. You should send a bug report (radar) to Apple.

Comment: I seem to recall this question being asked before (although I can't seem to find it now), and it is a known bug – see [SR-2636](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2636).

Comment: I will, i even tried an online compiler and it works. Looks more of a bug

Comment: Looks like the same problem as [How can I concatenate multiple optional strings in swift 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315692/how-can-i-concatenate-multiple-optional-strings-in-swift-3-0) (possible duplicate?)

Comment: FWIW, if this is real code, you shouldn't be using floating point for currency amounts. Either express them in cents/pence (e.g. 1099 instead of 10.99), or use a decimal floating point library (NSDecimalNumber is one such option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alway iterate through and add to total, much simpler that a line of long addition.

```
var totalCost: Double = 0
for each in menu {
    totalCost += each.value
}
print(totalCost)
```