# Possible Swift 3 Compiler bug: concatenating arrays of [UIButton]!

Tags: uibutton, swift3

I think I’ve just found the strangest bug in the swift compiler

If you try to concatenate two implicitly unwrapped arrays of buttons, works fine, but as soon as you try to concatenate a third array of the same type, it says `binary operator '+' cannot be applied to types [UIButton] and [UIButton]!` even though the first two arrays are implicitly unwrapped...

As in…

```
@IBOutlet var buttons1: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet var buttons2: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet var buttons3: [UIButton]!

var allButtons = button1 + button2 //this works
var allButtons = buttons1 + buttons2 + buttons3 //this doesn't…
```

Have duplicated this in a playground as well.

EDIT:

It looks like part of the problem is that the concatenation of `button1 + button2` produces a `[UIButton]` instead of `[UIButton]!`, even if I force unwrap the concatenation like so:

```
var allButtons = button1! + button2!
```

Also, even if I force the type of the variable it still doesn't work:

```
var allButtons: [UIButton]! = button1 + button2 + button3
```

Is this just something I'm blatantly missing, or is this a real bug?

**EDIT 2**

Well I found two workarounds. They both make sense given the result the concatenation of the first two arrays produces, but I still find it strange that the compiler wouldn't infer the types of all three given the statement. Is this expected behavior...?

```
var anotherAllButtons = button1 + button2 + (button3 as [UIButton])
var allButtons = (button1 + button2) as [UIButton]! + button3
```

Interestingly, the cast from [UIButton] to [UIButton]! would never fail, which makes me suspect that the compiler would infer the types correctly.

Comment: Probably the same kind of compiler bug than this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913093/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-inout-string-double-aka-inout-dictionary You should send a bug report to Apple.