# adding doubles contained within a dictionary swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary, double, swift3

I am learning a little bit about Swift and am following along with a Udemy course. The course is taught in swift 2 and I am using swift 3 so I am hoping to understand the difference in outputs and I cannot find any answer online thus far.
I have a dictionary item which contains 3 things.

```
var menu = ["entre" : 5.55, "main-meal": 20.50, "desert": 5.50]
```

The idea is to add the 3 values together using the instructors output (which works fine in swift 2):

```
var totalCost = menu["entre"]! + menu["desert"]! + menu["main-meal"]!
```

Within the course this works just fine but for me it throws an error that reads "Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [String : Double]' (aka 'inout Dictionary')"

What I find very odd is that if I only use 2 values, all is fine, the problem is when the third is added.  I can get around the issue by adding + 0.0 to the end as below:

```
var totalCost = menu["entre"]! + menu["desert"]! + menu["main-meal"]! + 0.0
```

What I am hoping to understand is what is the difference between the two versions and ideally what I am doing wrong in adding the 3 together without my workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Swift. You've found a bug on your first day! I've reported it to bugs.swift.org for you. Thanks!

Comment: If your dictionary values are all Double just change your dictionary type `var menu: [String: Double] = ["entre" : 5.55, "main-meal": 20.50, "desert": 5.50]
`

Comment: Wow, this is a whopper of a bug too. Impressive. In the meantime you can assign through temporaries, e.g. `let x = menu["entre"]!` `let y = menu["desert"]!` `let z = x + y`

Comment: I think this a definitely is type inference a bug in Swift 3.0.1/ Swift 3.0. As there is a big changes from Swift 2 [NSObject: AnyObject]  to Swift 3 [AnyHashable: Any].

Comment: @LeoDabus That won't work (try it).  This is an actual bug in the compiler, and affects both playgrounds and non-playgrounds.

Comment: @GaryLO How do you propose that will do anything?  The type of the dictionary is `[String: Double]` (whether explicit or implied).  You are making it so the addition expression won't work at all, but for other reasons!

Comment: @par , just from my observation, one of the force-unwrapped value force cast to Double will work. `var totalCost = menu["entre"]! as Double + menu["main-meal"]! + menu["desert"]!`.

Comment: @par Also if you tried specify the Type for totalCost. `var totalCost: Double = menu["entre"]! + menu["main-meal"]!  + menu["desert"]!`. It will throw `MyPlayground.playground:4:62: error: value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Comment: Well I don't feel too silly now.  Hopefully it can be resolved.

Leo Dabus, I did try that and had the same result, the only thing that made it work was to add the + 0.0 on the end.

@matt, thanks for reporting the bug for me.

Comment: @GaryLO There are various ways to make it work, the problem is that the code OP posted is syntactically valid and should work as-is. The type of `menu` is already `[String: Double]`!

Comment: @par You are right. As James has asked "the difference between the two versions". I just want pointed out that there are a big implementation changes for `collection` type and we all can't conclude wether it is related or not because it is a bug!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot subscript a value of type 'inout' \[String :Double\] (aka inout Dictionary<String, Double>)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913093/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-inout-string-double-aka-inout-dictionary)

Comment: @matt FYI there is already an existing bug report for this, [SR-2636](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2636).

Comment: Thanks, @Hamish, I'll mark that on my report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Workarounds

#### For a few keys

```
let (entreCost, desertCost, mainCost) = (menu["entre"]!, menu["desert"]!, menu["main-meal"]!)

let totalCost = entreCost + desertCost + mainCost
```

#### For a lot of keys

```
let keysToSum = ["entre", "desert", "main-meal"]
keysToSum.map{ menu[$0]!}.reduce(0, +)
```

#### For all keys

```
menu.values.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: `reduce` is probably a nicer solution to his original problem anyway. But wow what a bug 