# Dictionary error: Ambiguous reference to member '+'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have the following code in a swift 3 method:

```
let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3]
let sum = dict["A"]! + dict["B"]! + dict["C"]!
```

The code does not compile because of the `Ambiguous reference to member '+'` error. But if I try to add only two elements it compile and works as expected.

```
let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3]
let sum = dict["A"]! + dict["B"]!
```

Works normally.

Am I missing something from how the language should work?

Comment: Try to cast those references like: `Int(dict["A"]!) + Int(dict["B"]!)`

Comment: I think this is a bug in Swift unfortunately. :( You should be able to work around it by wrapping the first two in parenthesis like so: `(dict["A"]! + dict["B"!) + dict["C"]!`.

Comment: THIS SHOULD GO AS A BUG!!!!

Comment: @JacobKing it does not work by wrapping them together. But it does work when I force the type to `Int`.

Comment: Also see [cannot subscript a value of type 'inout' \[String :Double\] (aka inout Dictionary<String, Double>)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913093/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-inout-string-double-aka-inout-dictionary), and the [other bug report SR-2636](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2636)

Comment: @Hamish: I had not seen SR-2636: shouldn't that latter bug report have been flagged as a duplicate for the [former one, SR-1122](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1122)?

Comment: @dfri Quite possibly – it definitely looks like the same root cause. Although that being said, I can't say I know exactly what the criteria for a duplicate is over there (besides filing the occasional bug, I tend not to get involved).

Comment: @Hamish I'm likewise. Added a SO-like dupe comment nonetheless :)

Comment: you should declare the type like this:

`let dict: [String: Int] = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3]`

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:

```
let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3]
let sum = 0 + dict["A"]! + dict["B"]! + dict["C"]!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the error by wrapping `dict["A"]` with `Int`.

This will cast the value of the key "A" to an Int,allowing us to add properly.

```
let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3]
let sum = Int(dict["A"]!) + Int(dict["B"]!) + Int(dict["C"]!)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has been compiled successfully:

```
let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3]
let one = dict["A"]!
let two = dict["B"]!
let three = dict["C"]!
let sum = one + two + three
```

I guess, this problem related to complex expressions. You can read more about build time optimisation [in this article](https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/regarding-swift-build-time-optimizations-fc92cdd91e31#.twqn8hsv5).

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, this appears to be a bug. However, it seems like you are unlikely to encounter this, because it is quite unsafe to force unwrap a dictionary element like that. This works fine:

```
let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3]

if
  let a = dict["A"],
  let b = dict["B"],
  let c = dict["C"]
{
  let sum = a + b + c
}
```