# After updating to xcode 9.2 string showing issue of ambiguity

Tags: ios, swift

Before updating to xcode to 8.3 to xcode 9.2 it the string concatination is woring fine but now it's showing error like "**An ambiguous reference to member  +**  ". Please tell me is there is any syntax error of me in code though it was running previously.

```
mylable.text = "\(dicLabelData["part1"]!)" + "$\(aDict["part2"]!)" + "\(dicLabelData["part3"]!)"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `dicLabelData` declared as a `[String: String]`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41061252/dictionary-error-ambiguous-reference-to-member
This link might help!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315692/how-can-i-concatenate-multiple-optional-strings-in-swift-3-0

This is the actual post!

Comment: @ Larme  i don't have issue with that you can consider it as a dictionary and I want to show it's value there. so there is any need to [String: String] still

Comment: @NishuPriya Thanks it's a bug. It helped me.