# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'Float!'

Tags: swift, swift3

When I do the following:

```
let gapDuration = Float(self.MONTHS) * Float(self.duration) * self.gapMonthly;
```

I get the error:

```
Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'Float!'
```

But when I do:

```
let gapDuration = 12 * Float(self.duration) * self.gapMonthly;
```

Everything is working fine.
I have no Idea what this error is telling me.

`self.gapMonthly` is of type `Float!` and `self.duration` and `self.MONTHS` are of type `Int!`

Comment: Consider to use non-optional types as much as possible. For example could `months` be ever `nil` in practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider this a bug (at the very least, the error is misleading), and appears to be present when attempting to use a binary operator on 3 or more expressions that evaluate to a given type, where one or more of those expressions is an implicitly unwrapped optional of that type.

This simply stretches the type-checker too far, as it has to consider all possibilities of treating the IUO as a strong optional (as due to [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) the compiler will treat an IUO as a strong optional if it can be type-checked as one), along with attempting to find the correct overloads for the operators.

At first glance, it appears to be similar to the issue shown in [How can I concatenate multiple optional strings in swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36315692/2976878) – however that bug was fixed in Swift 3.1, but this bug is still present.

A minimal example that reproduces the same issue would be:

```
let a: Float! = 0

// error: Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'Float!'
let b = a * a * a
```

and is present for other binary operators other than `*`:

```
// error: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'Float!'
let b = a + a + a
```

It is also still reproducible when mixing in `Float` expressions (as long as at least one `Float!` expression remains), as well as when explicitly annotating `b` as a `Float`:

```
let b: Float = a * a * a // doesn't compile
```

```
let a: Float! = 0
let b: Int = 0
let c: Int = 0

let d: Float = a * Float(b) * Float(c) // doesn't compile
```

---

A simple fix for this would be to explicitly force unwrap the implicitly unwrapped optional(s) in the expression:

```
let d = a! * Float(b) * Float(c) // compiles
```

This relieves the pressure on the type-checker, as now all the expressions evaluate to `Float`, so overload resolution is much simpler.

Although of course, it goes without saying that this will crash if `a` is `nil`. In general, you should try and avoid using implicitly unwrapped optionals, and instead prefer to use strong optionals – and, as [@vadian says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250149/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-float-and-float/42251494#comment71658292_42250149), always use non-optionals in cases where the value being `nil` doesn't make sense.

If you need to use an optional and aren't 100% sure that it contains a value, you should safely unwrap it before doing the arithmetic. One way of doing this would be to use `Optional`'s [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map) method in order to propagate the optionality:

```
let a: Float! = 0
let b: Int = 0
let c: Int = 0

// the (a as Float?) cast is necessary if 'a' is an IUO,
// but not necessary for a strong optional.
let d = (a as Float?).map { $0 * Float(b) * Float(c) }
```

If `a` is non-nil, `d` will be initialized to the result of the unwrapped value of `a` multiplied with `Float(b)` and `Float(c)`. If however `a` is `nil`, `d` will be initialised to `nil`.